# How to compute a single Value-at-Risk (a single quantile) of portfolio returns taking into account correlation between individual returns?

Tags: correlation, value-at-risk, estimation, normal-distribution, multivariate

**Introduction**

My goal is to retrieve a single [Value-at-Risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk) (VaR) of a N(0, H) random variable $X$ at the $\alpha \in (0,1)$  confidence level where H is a known d-dimensional positive definite matrix (with $d >3$) In other words, I aim to retrieve the $\alpha$ quantile of a N(0, H) random variable $X$ , i.e.

$$\text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X) = \text{inf} \ \{x \in \mathbb{R}: F_X(x) > \alpha\}$$

I consider the $\text{VaR}_\alpha$ for $\alpha \in \{0.1, 0.05, 0.01\}$ in the context of a portfolio comprising $d>3$ financial log returns where we assume that the portfolio log return follows a multivariate normal distribution, i.e. N(0, w^T H w). We define w as an equally weighted vector of length $d$ meaning that each asset is equally represented in our portfolio. I do not wish to consider a reduced model in which the portfolio's returns are considered as a single univariate time series, i.e. N(0, $\sigma^2$), as this ignores complicated correlation among the individual returns. In this context VaR is the maximum loss with 1-$\alpha$ probability. The idea is to use VaR estimates in a backtesting analysis (Kupiec test, Christoffersen Test) in order to evaluate different models used for forecasting the covariance matrix H.

**Approach**

In case of unimodal symmetric distributions such as the multivariate normal distribution considered in the question, quantiles correspond to 
 [Highest Density Regions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148475/122737). As pointed out [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/354070/122737), the highest density region of an N(0,H) random variable is an ellipsoid centered at its mean, 0, and oriented per the covariance matrix H:

$$x: x^TH^{-1}x \le y$$

In order to find a single quantile that satisfies the definition of Value-at-Risk we proceed as follows: the set of solutions that satisfy the condition of the ellipsoid equation, the [level set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set), is retrieved by randomly generating many points on this ellipsoid. Then, I evaluate the portfolio return at each solution satisfying the condition: for example, let's suppose $s = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_d)$ is a solution/ point on the ellipsoid, then the portfolio return at this point will be $w\cdot s$, which corresponds to the mean of the solution vector because we stated that each asset is equally represented in the portfolio and $x_i \in s$ corresponds to the return of asset $i$. Consequently, the lowest return, the minimum, on the ellipsoid is the maximum loss.

**Question**

Now, in order to ensure that the maximum loss on the ellipsoid is the maximum loss with 1-$\alpha$ probability, hence is the Value-at-Risk of X at the $\alpha$ confidence level, I need to define the cutoff value for the ellipsoid, i.e. $y$. At this point, I am a bit confused concerning the definition of the cutoff value for the ellipsoid.

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/354070/122737) it is stated that the cutoff value for the ellipsoid can be determined from the Chi-square with d degrees of freedom. For instance, the highest density region capturing 0.95 probability of the N(0,H) is found with y= value such that Chi-square with d degrees of freedom 0.95. When defining the cutoff value from the chi-square with d degrees of freedom and following the procedure explained in the approach section, I would interpret the lowest return on the ellipsoid as the maximum loss with 0.95 probability, i.e. $\text{VaR}_{0.05}$. Is it correct to state that these maximum loss values are then the maximum loss with 1-α probability, hence is the Value-at-Risk? VaR does increase with a decrease in α but at the same time VaR seems a bit a large for the context which makes me doubt my interpretation and definition of the cutoff value for the ellipsoid determined from the Chi-square with d degrees of freedom and its link to the α quantile of the distribution (Value-at-Risk).

Any comments that could point me in the right direction are more than welcome.

**[Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51227013/5774055) code for obtaining random points on the ellipsoid**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm
from scipy.stats import ortho_group
from scipy.stats._continuous_distns import chi2

dim = 10
# Create a positive definite matrix H with shape (dim, dim).
# evals is the vector of eigenvalues of H.  This can be replaced
# with any vector of length `dim` containing positive values.
evals = (np.arange(1, dim + 1)/2)**2
# Use a random orthogonal matrix to generate H.
R = ortho_group.rvs(dim)
H = R.T.dot(np.diag(evals).dot(R))

# y determines the level set to be computed.
y = chi2.ppf(q=0.95, df=dim)   
# Generate random points on the ellipsoid
nsample = 100000
r = np.random.randn(H.shape[0], nsample)
# u contains random points on the hypersphere with radius 1.
u = r / np.linalg.norm(r, axis=0)
xrandom = sqrtm(H).dot(np.sqrt(y)*u)
# Compute maximum loss on the ellipsoid
xrandom_min = np.min(np.array([np.mean(x) for x in xrandom.T]))
print("Maximum loss i.e. Value-at-Risk:")
print(xrandom_min)
```

Answer (score 2):

With a multivariate normal model, the portfolio has a univariate normal distribution (mean and variance are easy), so it reduces to a scaled univariate quantile.

Comment: The reduced models (univariate method) ignores the complicated correlation among the individual returns. I explicitly want to take this information into account hence I do prefer not to consider portfolio return as a univariate series with mean and variance.

Comment: But you're assuming the log-returns follow a multidimensional distribution, right? And the portfolio composition is held fixed? Then the total log return of the portfolio reduces to a univariate distribution, as it's just the sum of normally distributed log returns. This is an exact result based on your assumptions; nothing is ignored. I'm not sure what you mean by "complicated correlations" -- the correlations are all fully accounted for.

Comment: I have a follow-up question; when our portfolio contains, let's say, m different returns and we aim to compute the Value at risk based on the covariance-variance method, it is important to check the multivariate normal assumption or univariate assumption.